# Compose array of Functions using stream

Tags: java, function, java-8, java-stream

I want to compose an array of functions to one function. Given multiple functions the method should return a function which is the composition of the input functions.

One way to do this is

```
public static <T> Function<T,T> composeAll(Function<T,T>... functions){
    Function<T,T> res = Function.identity();
    for(Function<T,T> f : functions){
       res = res.compose(f);
    }
    return res;
}
```

I'm looking to achieve the same result by first making a stream of the array of functions. But I can't figure out how to do this

```
public static <T> Function<T,T> composeAll2 (Function<T,T>... functions){
    Function<T,T> res = Function.identity();
    Arrays.stream(functions). ??? 
    return res;
}
```

What code should I enter in the last method where I put question marks now?

Comment: You'll want some sort of [reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html), which is comparable to a `fold` in a functional language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make use of the [`Stream#reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) operation:

```
public static <T> Function<T,T> composeAll2 (Function<T,T>... functions){
    return Arrays.stream(functions).reduce(Function.identity(), Function::compose);
}
```

Which is identical to your iterative way of composing functions.

Comment: `reduce(Function::compose).orElse(Function.identity())` may produce slightly more efficient functions (esp. memory-wise when the array is rather small), but they are semantically equivalent.

Comment: @Holger maybe even use `reduce(Function::comopose).orElseGet(Function::identity)` which might be even more efficient

Comment: Given the current implementation where `Function.identity()` always returns the same instance, produced via lambda expression, there is nothing, another method reference like `Function::identity` could improve here, as it won’t invoke `identity()`, but create an instance representing `Function::identity`. The advantage of `orElseGet` only materializes when it can defer a truly expensive operation.

Answer (score 5):

While @Lino's answer is concise, it is unsafe and prone to stack overflow:

```
List<Function<Integer, Integer>> list = Collections.nCopies(10000, i -> i + 1);
System.out.println(composeAll2(list.toArray(new Function[0])).apply(0));
```

If you run this code, it will fail with StackOverflowError:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.function.Function.lambda$compose$0(Function.java:68)
    at java.util.function.Function.lambda$compose$0(Function.java:68)
    at java.util.function.Function.lambda$compose$0(Function.java:68)
    at java.util.function.Function.lambda$compose$0(Function.java:68)
    at java.util.function.Function.lambda$compose$0(Function.java:68)
    at java.util.function.Function.lambda$compose$0(Function.java:68)
    ...
```

To avoid this, I suggest not using streams at all and using the old `for-each` loop:

```
public static <T> Function<T,T> composeAll2(Function<T,T>... functions){
    return input -> {
        T res = input;
        for (Function<T, T> f : functions) {
            res = f.apply(res);
        }
        return res;
    };
}
```

This version of `composeAll2` will use a constant stack space.

Comment: Nice answer, but the varargs parameter leads me to believe stack overflow is not a real concern.

Comment: I think your approach is good, but when would you need to compose 10000 functions?

Comment: @Lino It's rather common in functional programming where you often need to perform a lot of transformations on immutable structures

Comment: Mind the difference between `compose` and `andThen`.

Comment: @Holger It can easily be fixed by traversing the array in reverse order

Comment: The disadvantage is that for every call to the returned function the for loop is invoked, which might lead to slightly less good performance depending on the operations you're composing